# What properties are used to assert that there is always a number between two given numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

What properties of "numbers" are used to assert that for given numbers $a$ and $b$, $a≠b$, there exists a number $x$ such that $a < x < b$ ?

In the texts I've read, this seems to be assumed without explanation in discussions that are otherwise quite careful about such things.

For example, in Spivak's *Calculus* (4E, p. 123) this fact is used to demonstrate that the function $f(x) = x^2$ does not take on its maximum on the interval (0,1) because for any $0 ≤ y < 1$ there is an $x$ such that $y < x < 1$. Up to that point, the only properties of "numbers" (whatever they may be) that have been defined are those of an ordered field, and it is not clear to me that this property can be derived from those.

I gather this amounts to the "numbers" in question having "dense order". (Correct me if I'm wrong.) But I'm unclear where that comes from.

Also note: up to the point where this question arises, there has been no mention of what "numbers" *are* (i.e., whether they are $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$), only that they have the properties of an ordered field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is easy to show that in any ordered field if $a < b$, then $a < \frac{a + b}{2} < b$. In any ordered field 2 is invertible, so this intermediate value exists.

Comment: Indeed! I think that's the answer I was looking for. So just to break this down further the be sure I'm not missing something: the reason I can divide by 2 is that the multiplicative inverse of 2 exists if 2 does. Similar reasoning leads to $\mathbb Q$. Correct?

Comment: And so that I don't appear to be to much of an idiot: In the texts I'm reading, at the point where my question arises, there's no specification of what "numbers" mean, other than a specification of the properties they have. Hence my question (and the appropriateness of this answer).

Comment: yes; even more "broken down" from the very beginning: 1)Big Bang 2)1 is in $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb R$ is a field. 3)By closure of operations, 1+1 is also in $\mathbb R$ 3)As you said, in a field**, every nonzero element is invertible, and **$ \mathbb R$ does not have characteristic 2, i.e., the above result is not true in fields of characteristic 2; and trivially not true for the field of 2 elements by cardinality reasons alone--there is no third element that could be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Aren't there ordered fields of characteristic 2? If so, 2 would not be invertible there.

Comment: Since you are interested in field properties, maybe this would be a full(er) argument: 1 is in $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb R$ is a field. In $\mathbb R$ with its standard ordering, 1>0. By closure axioms, 1+1 is in the field, and by order axioms, 1+1=2>0. As a nonzero element, 2 has an inverse called $\frac {1}{2}$ , which is larger than 0. Then $a-\frac {a+b}{2}=\frac{a-b}{2}>0 $ since $a>b$

Comment: @gary: No, there are no ordered fields of finite characteristic. If $F$ is a field, then $1\neq 0$, so either $1\lt 0$ or $1\gt 0$. But $1=1^2$ and squares are always positive in an ordered field, so $1\gt 0$. Adding $1$ to both we get $2\gt 1 \gt 0$; add $1$ again to get $3\gt 2\gt 1\gt 0$. Inductively, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$, $n\gt 0$, hence $n\neq 0$; thus, $F$ does not have positive characteristic.

Comment: @Arturo: thanks again; very clear and helpful--as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If we just assume connectedness of the reals, if there were no numbers between y and 1, we would be lead to the contradiction that we could then  express $\mathbb R= (-\infty,y]\cup[1,\infty)$, i.e., $\mathbb R$ is the union of two sets with disjoint closure, i.e., we get a disconnection of $\mathbb R$, as the union of two non-disjoint sets, or as the union of non-empty separated sets.

Alternatively,using field properties, if we assume $\frac {1}{2}$ is in $\mathbb R$ ($1$ is in $\mathbb R$, then so is $1+1$, then so is $(1+1)^{-1})$, then so is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all natural n. By the Archimedean property , there is some integer $m$ such that $\frac{1}{2^m}<1-y$ by field closure properties then, $y+\frac {1}{2^m}$ is a real number, but $y+\frac{1}{2^m}<1$.

EDIT: 3rd paragraph removed, since I have no good proof for it.

Comment: But it is much harder to prove that $\mathbb R$ is connected than it is to show that there is an element between $a<b$ in an ordered field.  I hope this doesn't sound too negative, because this is a good point in the case of $\mathbb R$, but this method assumes more and gives less than taking $\frac{a+b}{2}$.  E.g., it wouldn't show that there is a rational between two rationals.

Comment: I had a proof similar to Oliver's in mind, but when I saw his, I ended up using something else; maybe the lub property. No problem, tho, I welcome input.

Comment: That's understandable, as there's no point covering the same ground.  I took the question to be about a way to show this before the notion of completeness is introduced (and the l.u.b. property is equivalent to connectedness for ordered fields).  If you do assume the l.u.b. property, then you get the Archimedean property, from which you can deduce the stronger conclusion that there is a rational between $a<b$.

Comment: Jonas: I added an argument from the perspective of the field properties of $\mathbb R$, which uses the $LUB$, I guess in the background.

Comment: gary: I see.  I'm not really sure why you used $1/2^n$ rather than $1/n$ (or $(1-y)/2$), but that argument using the Archimedean property makes sense.  This is a nitpick, but it could be mentioned that the fact that $(1+1)^{-1}$ exists is a consequence of the fact that $1+1\neq 0$ (because $1>0\implies 1+1>0$).

Comment: No problem, Jonas, always good to refresh the material. Still, Oliver's post was shorter and really got to the heart-of-the matter more clearly.

Comment: My question arises before the discussion of connectedness or even $\mathbb R$. But your construction of $\frac {1}{2}$ is helpful, thanks.

Comment: No problem, raxa; what  can I say; I seem to have a knack for not answering questions suited for the OP, or of misunderstanding--or misunderestimating--questions.

Comment: btw: aren't you that raxacorifallapatorius jackson from my highschool in NYC?

Comment: The third paragraph, added 5 hours ago, uses what it supposed to show.  Why is $1$ the least upper bound of $\{y:y<1\}$?  Precisely because for all $a<1$ there exists $y$ with $a<y<1$.

Comment: But couldn't we argue that if 1 were not the LUB, then it must be some c, but we would then need y<c<1, since y>y does not hold. Then, arguing by cases, whether 1 is the LUB or not, there are some intermediate elements.

Comment: Anyway, I worry that the people running this site will put a hit on me from all my obsessive edits and re-edits; I'll try to tone it down.

Comment: @Jonas: I had an explanation for this. I will delete this part until I have time to write a better explanation.